# Filter a dictionary to return certain keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have been trying to look at other questions and not found an answer that sufficiently solves my problem. I have a list if dictionaries that contains many keys, and want to return a list of dictionaries which contain only three of these keys.

```
dict_keys(['dropoff_datetime', 'dropoff_latitude', 'dropoff_longitude', 'fare_amount', 'imp_surcharge', 'mta_tax', 'passenger_count', 'payment_type', 'pickup_datetime', 'pickup_latitude', 'pickup_longitude', 'rate_code', 'tip_amount', 'tolls_amount', 'total_amount', 'trip_distance', 'vendor_id'])
```

I Write a function called parse_trips(trips) that returns a list of the trips with only the following attributes:

```
trip_distance
pickup_latitude
pickup_longitude
```

I have tried so many iterations of this, and would be happy to use either map or filter, of which i have tried many variations to no success.

```
def parse_trips(trips):
new_list = []
for trip in trips:
    return trips['trip_distance'], trips['pickup_latidude'], trips['pickup_longitude']

parsed_trips = parse_trips(trips)
parsed_trips and parsed_trips[0]
```

This is the output i'm trying to get

```
# {'pickup_latitude': '40.64499',
#  'pickup_longitude': '-73.78115',
#  'trip_distance': '18.38'}
```

Comment: Do you want to select these three keys from any dictionary? Or only take dictionaries with only these three keys?

Comment: To clarify: the `trips` parameter is a list of dictionaries that contain the keys `trip_distance`, `pickup_latidude`, `pickup_longitude`? Do you want to return just one dictionary with those values? Or a list of dictionaries with those keys?

Comment: I want to return a list of dictionaries with those keys, zmike, essentially removing all the other keys and values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with needed keys and their respective values via dictionary comprehension and add it to `new_list`

```
#List of keys you need
needed_keys = ['trip_distance', 'pickup_latitude', 'pickup_longitude']

#Iterate over trips list
for trip in trips:

    #Create a dictionary with needed keys and their respective values and add it to result
    new_list.append({k:trip[k] for k in needed_keys})
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that you have *all* the keys in your target dictionaries, so you can use the builtin `all()` function to verify that each key in your target list of needed keys exist.

And then you keep only those trips.

After that, you can access any fields from your parsed trips.

```
needed_keys = ['trip_distance', 'pickup_latitude', 'pickup_longitude']
parsed_trips = [trip for trip in trips if all(key in trip for key in needed_keys)]
```

If you want to only return those 3 keys in your final list, you can pull them out with:

```
parsed_trips = [{k: trip[k] for k in needed_keys} for trip in trips if all(key in trip for key in needed_keys)]
```

Although I think the list/dict comprehensions there start getting a little long and ugly, so you may want to switch to a traditional `for` loop instead.

As a side note, you could always skip any trips where `trip.get('target_field') is None`, because the `.get()` won't throw you an index error, because it defaults to returning `None` if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```py
needed_keys = ['trip_distance', 'pickup_latitude', 'pickup_longitude']

for d in dicts:
    for k in [ key for key in d.keys() if not key in needed_keys ]:
        d.pop( k, None )
```

**MWE**

```py
keys = ['dropoff_datetime', 'dropoff_latitude', 'dropoff_longitude', 'fare_amount', 'imp_surcharge', 'mta_tax', 'passenger_count', 'payment_type', 'pickup_datetime', 'pickup_latitude', 'pickup_longitude', 'rate_code', 'tip_amount', 'tolls_amount', 'total_amount', 'trip_distance', 'vendor_id']
needed_keys = ['trip_distance', 'pickup_latitude', 'pickup_longitude']

dicts = []
for i in range(10):
    dicts.append( { i:iii for iii,i in enumerate(keys) } )

for d in dicts:
    for key in [ key for key in d.keys() if not key in needed_keys ]:
        d.pop( key, None )
```